# Configuration of JWT expiration time in Okta (OpenID Connect)

Tags: authentication, configuration, jwt, openid-connect, okta

Is it possible to configure jwt token expiration time (`exp` property) for an Okta OpenId Connect application?

It seems to be set to 1 hour from issuing time (`iat` property) for both implicit and authorization code grants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the expiration time of our OIDC tokens is not configurable and is indeed fixed to 1 hour. It's up to your app to use the refresh token and ask for a new access token (in the authorization code flow scenario) or simply call the authorize endpoint again to get a newer token (in the case of the implicit flow).